When characterizing the qubit, does it always actually collapses into $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ state?
For the qubit coupled with resonator (superconducting qubit, to be more precise) the typical $T_1$ and $T_2$ characterization looks like the following:


From the above figures it is clear that there are many points between states $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ that have been experimentally measured.
But for the double-slit experiment, when we measure (as I understand it correctly), we collapse the quantum state to either possible states/outcomes (I'm very sorry for some incorrect terminology).
What is the interpretation of the qubit state measured in between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states?

In this specific figure, its just given as an average of the measurement outcomes. The states are either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ after the measurement, but observed at different ratios depending on the actual state that it was in before the measurement.
For example, in (a) we begin in the $|1\rangle$ state, and we leave the qubit alone for an amount of time specified by the bottom axis. We then measure it, collapsing it into either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. We repeat this many times for each value of time, then plot the % occurrance on the vertical axis. If we see the same number of $|0\rangle$ measurements as $|1\rangle$, it would be plotted in the middle.
This is showing that even when we leave the qubit alone, its slowly decaying from $|1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ due to noise from the environment.

what about single-shot measurements, where averaging is not used?

Each single shot is exactly a $|0\rangle$ or a $|1\rangle$ state, as you'd expect, but you don't learn much about the pre-measurement state from that

for single-shot measurements it is also possible to prepare some mixed state: for example, I've preliminary prepared single-shot $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ states (~2000 shots for each), I can plot these states as so-called "clouds", then I can prepare mixed state, this state will be exactly in between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ clouds, and this is the issue, according to double-slit experiment I would expect to see the points of the mixed state either in $|0\rangle$ or in $|1\rangle$ cloud.

I have no idea what you mean and how it applies to the double slit experiment
